# When would a reference be zero-initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer

§8.5/6 in draft [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) says:

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - ...
> - if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

I'd like to have an example of a reference that is zero-initialized.

Comment: huh? what? that is not possible

Comment: @yngum: But how can a reference be uninitialized is probably the OPs questiont hen

Comment: @BЈовић: if so then the follow-up question is, "why does the standard contain language to cover an impossible case?". And if not then the follow-up question is, "why does the standard permit a nonsensical case?" :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza he means [dcl.init]/5

Comment: @SteveJessop The point is "if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.". I am not an English native speaker, but I interpret that as "unitialized". I am not sure why they put it there, but g++ 4.8.1 throws an error trying to compile this `int & a{};`

Comment: `using type = int&; type();`

Comment: Note, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/4653479#4653479) provides links to many of the draft standards.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Very useful. Tks.

Comment: Since references are always initialised to an explicit value, isn't this just saying that in cases where a variable gets set to zero (like static), a reference does not? Clunky language, but the meaning seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Later the standard says "Every object of static storage duration is zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization takes place." So if you have e.g. in global scope

```
int x;
int& r = x;
```

r is first zero-initialized, and then initialized by x. For reference, zero-initialized means nothing, so it is mere technicality.

Comment: Note that a reference is *not necessarily* an object. An object is a region of storage, but it's unspecified whether a reference requires any storage. This doesn't change the validity of your answer though.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Make it a class type with a reference member.

Comment: @JosephMansfield In Standardese references and objects are distinct. The precise wording that Wojtek is alluding to goes (emphasis mine): ‘**Variables** with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.’ Variables can have a reference type.